# Horizontal screen tearing on Ubuntu 16.04 (Mostly at the upper side of the monitor)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

Watch this video
https://youtu.be/7-c5o3eNHuY

Device : Dell Inspiron 3000 series notebook

Intel Display graphic with Nvidia 820M 3D Acceleration graphic card.

Destros that I tried : Linux Mint 17.3, 18, Ubuntu 16.04 but all have the same problem.

I am new to the Linux and this is the only problem that is annoying too much. 
Any help will be great.

Comment: I thought the problem will be recognized much more clearly with a video.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comment because there was a typo. You can keep the video if you want; all I am saying is there will be people who do not want to watch a 1-minute long video and prefer all relevant info to be within this post. Moreover, you definitely don't need to use a video to demonstrate screen tearing; still screenshots will suffice.

Comment: Are you connecting with hdmi cable? I don't see it on old vga cable, but do in hdmi. I used nvidia-settings to change to internal intel video. That solved it for noe